# How to have multiple attribute directives, each with its own 'callback', without triggering the multidir error in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'd like to apply two attribute directives to an element - let's call them `my-draggable` and `my-resizable` - and I need to pass each one a callback for drag and resize completion actions. These directives are meant to be used independently if needed.

Now, for a single directive scneario I would do this

```
scope:{
  callback: '&'
}
```

but if I do that for two, I know this way each directive will create its own isolated scope and that's a no-no, resulting in *'Error: $compile:multidir Multiple Directive Resource Contention'*.

I'd very much appreciate some tips in handling this kind of situations.

Here's the fiddle showcasing my (non-functioning) scenario:
http://jsfiddle.net/crotundu/Ed9uP/2/

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ed9uP/5/) to call your callback functions in the link function you'll obviously want to change that.

Markup: (note the removal of the parenthesis on the callbacks)

```
<my-widget data-provider="data" 
   my-draggable drag-callback="dragDone" 
   my-resizable resize-callback="resizeDone"></my-widget>
```

Directives: (you will need to inject in `$parse` and remove the isolate scope)

```
$parse(scope[attrs.dragCallback])();

$parse(scope[attrs.resizeCallback])();
```